# JTable Missing Column Headers

Tags: java, swing, jtable, invisible, jtableheader

Really simple question. Don't bash me please. :)

I created a table model by extending `AbstractTableModel` as follows:

```
public class InventoryTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = { "On Sale", "Name", "Selling Price", "Description" };

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[columnIndex];
      }    

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return null;
    }    
}
```

Next, I create a `JTable` using this table model and show it in a panel with layout `BorderLayout`:

```
JTable inventoryTable = new JTable(new InventoryTableModel());        
mainPanel.add(inventoryTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Note that `mainPanel` eventually ends up inside a scroll pane:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView(mainPanel);
```

For some reason I am not seeing the table headers. Here is all my program shows:

[image: Missing Column Headers]

(Note, the white space is where the table is.)

To make sure the table is being placed properly I modified the `getRowCount` method to return 1:

```
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return 1;
}
```

And now this is what I see:

[image: Missing Column Headers - 1 Row]

Can anyone tell me why my column headers are missing? I know it's something simple but my brain is fried and I just can't seem to figure it out.

Thank you.

Update, based on [Josh M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22734780/2587435) I placed the table inside a scroll pane. That worked but this is how my application looks now:

[image: Table Inside Scroll Pane]

Note the vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
mainPanel.add(inventoryTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

To

```
mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(inventoryTable), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Does a JTable always have to live inside a scroll pane? Also, did you see my updated post that says mainPanel resides in a scroll pane?

Comment: It doesn't have to be in a `JScrollPane` but if you don't put it in one, you have to add the table header and the table separately. It's just easier to put it in a `JScrollPane`. Plus if your data exceeds the bounds of its container, you can scroll.

Comment: Check out my updated post. Do you know why doing as you suggested causes the scroll pane (the outer scroll pane) to show the vertical scrollbar?